# Trouble getting my calculator program to work in android...shows nullpointerexception

Tags: android

My calculator program just doesnt seem to work. It crashes everytime i click on a number button. Please help.Thanks in advance

The logcat report:

```
01-17 16:08:46.949: D/AndroidRuntime(321): Shutting down VM
    01-17 16:08:46.949: W/dalvikvm(321): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x4001d800)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at net.learn.calc.CalciActivity.handlenumber(CalciActivity.java:189)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at net.learn.calc.CalciActivity$9.onClick(CalciActivity.java:110)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    01-17 16:08:46.969: E/AndroidRuntime(321):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here's the program:

```
package net.learn.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalciActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText ent=null;
Button a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,add,sub,mul,div,equ,dot,cl,del;
double num=0;
int operator=1;
boolean clearrdy=false;
boolean numbpre=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.zero);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    c=(Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
    d=(Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
    e=(Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
    f=(Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
    g=(Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
    h=(Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
    i=(Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
    j=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.plus);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.minus);
    mul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    div=(Button)findViewById(R.id.divide);
    equ=(Button)findViewById(R.id.equal);
    dot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.decimal);
    cl=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    del=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(0);
        }
    });
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(1);
        }
    });
    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(2);
        }
    });
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(3);
        }
    });
    e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(4);
        }
    });
  f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handlenumber(5);
        }
    });
  g.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handlenumber(6);
    }
});
  h.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handlenumber(7);
    }
});
  i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handlenumber(8);
    }
});
  j.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handlenumber(9);
    }
});
  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handleop(1);
    }
});
 sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handleop(2);
    }
});
 mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handleop(3);
    }
});
 div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handleop(4);
    }
});
 equ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handleop(0);
    }
});
 dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handledecimal();
    }
});
 cl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        reset1();
    }
});
 del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        backsp1();
    }
});

}
public void handlenumber(int n)
{
    String str=ent.getText().toString();
    if(clearrdy)
    {
        str="";
        clearrdy=false;
    }
    String val=Integer.toString(n);
   str=str+val;
   ent.setText(str);
   ent.setSelection(str.length());

   numbpre=true;
}
public void handledecimal()
{ String str=ent.getText().toString();
    if(clearrdy)
    {
        str="0.";

    }
    else
    {
        str=str+".";

    }
    ent.setText(str);
    ent.setSelection(str.length());
    clearrdy=false;
    numbpre=true;
}
public void handleop(int newop)
{
    if(numbpre)
    {
        switch(operator)
        {
        case 1:
        num=num + Double.parseDouble(ent.getText().toString());
        break;
        case 2:
        num=num - Double.parseDouble(ent.getText().toString());
        break;
        case 3:
        num=num * Double.parseDouble(ent.getText().toString());
        break;
        case 4:
        num=num/Double.parseDouble(ent.getText().toString());
        break;
        }
    }
    String str=Double.toString(num);
    ent.setText(str);
    ent.setSelection(str.length());
    numbpre=false;
    clearrdy=true;
    operator=newop;
}
public void reset1()
{
    numbpre=false;
    clearrdy=false;
    operator=1;
    num=0;
}
public void backsp1()
{
     String str=ent.getText().toString();
       if (str.length() > 0) {
        str=str.substring(0,str.length() - 1);
        ent.setText(str);
        ent.setSelection(str.length());

}
}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="29dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/equal"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="250dp"
           android:layout_y="407dp"
           android:text="=" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/divide"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="180dp"
           android:layout_y="403dp"
           android:text="/" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/multiply"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="250dp"
           android:layout_y="324dp"
           android:text="X" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/nine"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="176dp"
           android:layout_y="322dp"
           android:text="9" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/seven"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="38dp"
           android:layout_y="322dp"
           android:text="7" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/eight"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="107dp"
           android:layout_y="322dp"
           android:text="8" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/zero"
           android:layout_width="58dp"
           android:layout_height="72dp"
           android:layout_x="107dp"
           android:layout_y="403dp"
           android:text="0" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/decimal"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="36dp"
              android:layout_y="403dp"
              android:text="." />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/five"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="105dp"
              android:layout_y="247dp"
              android:text="5" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/four"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="36dp"
              android:layout_y="243dp"
              android:text="4" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/six"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="174dp"
              android:layout_y="247dp"
              android:text="6" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/minus"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="246dp"
              android:layout_y="245dp"
              android:text="-" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/three"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="174dp"
              android:layout_y="168dp"
              android:text="3" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/two"
              android:layout_width="59dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="104dp"
              android:layout_y="168dp"
              android:text="2" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/one"
              android:layout_width="57dp"
              android:layout_height="70dp"
              android:layout_x="40dp"
              android:layout_y="168dp"
              android:text="1" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/plus"
              android:layout_width="58dp"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:layout_x="244dp"
              android:layout_y="170dp"
              android:text="+" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="88dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="194dp"
                    android:layout_y="116dp"
                    android:text="DEL" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/clear"
                    android:layout_width="84dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="66dp"
                    android:layout_y="118dp"
                    android:text="C" />

 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: First of all I would suggest u to make use of array...try to compact ur code...

Comment: Do your buttons exist in the main layout? Run some simple checks, is 'a' null, is `handlernumber` being called etc? Your code could be simplified massively BTW, that is not nice code. Edit: Looking at it, mostly it errors as `ent` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you don't assign `ent` to any control (all you have is `EditText ent=null;`), so you get a null error when calling:

```
String str=ent.getText().toString();
```

Comment: fish...my bad...thanks...i know its not nice code...im only a week into android...still getting the hang of it.